# <google-chart> does not work inside <template is="dom-bind">

Tags: google-visualization, polymer, google-web-component

<google-chart> element is not working for me (does not display anything) when inside <template> (<template is="dom-bind"> on the main document or in other element's <template>). On the other hand it works when I put it outside <template is="dom-bind"> on the main document.

https://jsbin.com/fivamu/edit?html,output

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org">
  <script src="/components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="/components/polymer/polymer.html">
  <link rel="import" href="/components/google-web-components/google-web-components.html">
</head>

<body>
  <template is="dom-bind">
    <h2>Doesn't work here:</h2>
    <google-chart type='geo' data='[["Country", "Popularity"],["Germany", 200],["United States", 300],["Brazil", 400],["Canada", 500],["France", 600],["RU", 700]]'></google-chart>
  </template>
  <h2>Works here:</h2> 
  <google-chart type='geo' data='[["Country", "Popularity"],["Germany", 200],["United States", 300],["Brazil", 400],["Canada", 500],["France", 600],["RU", 700]]'></google-chart>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work (tested in your jsbin):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org">
  <script src="/components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="/components/polymer/polymer.html">
  <link rel="import" href="/components/google-web-components/google-web-components.html">
</head>
<body>      
  <template id="t" is="dom-bind">
    <h2>Doesn't work here:</h2>
    <google-chart id='map'></google-chart>
  </template>
  <h2>Works here:</h2>    
  <google-chart type='geo' data='[["Country", "Popularity"],["Germany", 200],["United States", 300],["Brazil", 400],["Canada", 500],["France", 600],["RU", 700]]'></google-chart>
</body>


<script>
  var t = document.querySelector('#t');  

  // The dom-change event signifies when the template has stamped its DOM.
  t.addEventListener('dom-change', function() {
    // auto-binding template is ready.
    console.log('ready');
    var map = document.querySelector('#map');
    map.setAttribute('type', 'geo');
    map.setAttribute('data', '[["Country", "Popularity"],["Germany", 200],["United States", 300],["Brazil", 400],["Canada", 500],["France", 600],["RU", 700]]');
  });
</script>
</html>
```

The [google-chart](https://github.com/GoogleWebComponents/google-chart/blob/master/google-chart.html) element relies on async calls to Google APIs. If these calls do not resolve before the template has stamped its DOM, the google-chart is incomplete. Adding the data field [after the auto-binding template is ready](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/templates.html#dom-bind) will simulate the behaviour outside of a template.

Answer (score 2):

Try to add spaces between the square brackets:

```
data='[ ["Country", "Popularity"],["Germany", 200],["France", 600],["RU", 700] ]'
```

Comment: Just curious. Why does this solve the problem? It miraculously solved it but I don't understand why

Comment: Probably an issue with the property parser since `[[...]]` is also used for one-way binding.